# ES5-Shim usage and requirement

Tags: javascript

The official explanation for this terms is

> es5-shim.js and es5-shim.min.js monkey-patch a JavaScript context to contain all EcmaScript 5 methods that can be faithfully emulated with a legacy JavaScript engine.

However that just does not help me understand what it is and when should it be used ?

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, currently you only need to use it if you still have to support IE8-. IE9+ and other browsers are ES5-ready.